# PHP/Mysql - Check for existing entry in DB

Tags: php

Im using PHP to parse some XML, I take 3 details from each entry in the XML - Title, Description and ID.

The ID is unique and I store the ID along with title and description in a database. Im running the parse script via CRON so to prevent duplicates I want to first check the database to see if the ID of the entry already exists in the database.

How can I do this?

This will get my all the ID's right?

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM updates");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($id);

    if ($entry->id != $row) {
        Insert
    } else {
        echo 'Duplicate';
    }
```

Open to ideas?

Does that give me an array that I can compare the ID in the XML to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM updates");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($id);

    if ($entry->id != $row['id']) {
        Insert
    } else {
        echo 'Duplicate';
    }
```

it returns array form, so you have to give it column index or name to match

Comment: This appears to be fetching a single row, I'd like to check multiple rows for the occurance of the ID. How can I extend the above to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have your DBMS handle conflicting ids.

you can use the [ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) option of INSERT to handle that event let your DB automatically choose another ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   $id = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM updates where id = " . $entry->id);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($id);
   if ($row[0]) {
    insert
   }
   else {
   }
   ```
2. if uoy are makes the field unique then if you simply try to insert row - db rise an error "unique constraint". in this case you just have not to check if the record is unique. it will not be inserted anyway.